# Dynamically adding TextBlock using C# in Windows store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am creating a Windows 8 app using C#.
In one of the pages I need to display a random sentence with each word having a different color. I want to do it dynamically and not using the .xaml file.
Is there a way to dynamically add text blocks for this?
Any other approach is also welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to create controls programatically in the codebehind, an example inventing names:

```
TextBlock colorText = new TextBlock();
colortext.Foreground= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);

this.Panel.Children.Add(colortext)
```

Comment: You can do it in the Page's codebehind any time after the constructor. Or, if you want to do it in the constructor, any time after `InitializeComponents()` is called.

Comment: codebehind is the .cs file with the same name as the .xaml file